# Enabling GAE throws an error stating that one already exists, when it doesn't

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I recently took over a very old GCP project that seemingly wasn't being used, but behind the scene seems to be in a corrupt state. Let me explain. (actual domain/project ID replaced with placeholder)

1. Using gcloud CLI, it is shown that no GAE application exist, but when I try to create one, it tells me it already contains one.

```
$ gcloud --project projectId app describe
ERROR: (gcloud.app.describe) The current Google Cloud project [projectId] does not contain an App Engine application. Use `gcloud app create` to initialize an App Engine application within the project.

$ gcloud --project projectId app create --region asia-east1
ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) The project [projectId] already contains an App Engine application. You can deploy your application using `gcloud app deploy`.
```

Running app deploy results in the same error as create.

2. Using gcloud CLI, I was able to see that there is a custom domain registered, even though supposedly no GAE app exists. But when I try to delete it, it tells me that app does not exist.

```
$ gcloud --project projectId app domain-mappings list
ID                    SSL_CERTIFICATE_ID  SSL_MANAGEMENT_TYPE  PENDING_AUTO_CERT
subdomain.domain.com                      MANUAL

$ gcloud --project projectId app domain-mappings delete subdomain.domain.com
ERROR: (gcloud.app.domain-mappings.delete) NOT_FOUND: App does not exist.
```

3. Browsing to this custom domain brings user to a GAE instance in a **DIFFERENT** GCP project. So effectively this "ghost" custom domain that lives in this unused project, is somehow pointing to a **DIFFERENT** GCP project's GAE instance. We verified this because any updates made to the other project is reflected when browsing to this custom domain.

Factors I have eliminated are permission and billing issues. Under **IAM & Admin -> Manage Resources**, I am able to see the project ID correctly, there is also no resources pending deletion, and the project is tied to a billing account properly. Just to be extra safe, I granted myself owner rights but the issue persists.

These mindtwisting behaviour is leading me to believe this project is so old it is stuck in some legacy limbo state, where this project is somehow linked to the other, but I really cannot find an explanation for these weird behaviours. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 1) Run this **gcloud** CLI command: **gcloud projects list**. Does the Project_ID appear? 2) In the Google Cloud GUI go to **IAM & Admin** -> **Manage Resources**. Does the Project ID appear? 3) Also check under **RESOURCES PENDING DELETION** 4) In the GUI go to **Billing** -> **Account Management**. Does the project appear? 5) If you can access the project using those methods, what problem now appears. 6) If you cannot access the project and it is not attached to the billing account, then the project may have been deleted or you do not have permission. Edit your question with details.

Comment: To me this sound alike a DNS problem ...try to create GAE app for custom domain, then remove it.

Comment: @JohnHanley I went through what you listed and none of them seem to show any problems, answer inline:

1) Run this gcloud CLI command: gcloud projects list. Does the Project_ID appear? **Yes**
2) In the Google Cloud GUI go to IAM & Admin -> Manage Resources. Does the Project ID appear? **Yes**
3) Also check under RESOURCES PENDING DELETION **"You do not have any resources pending deletion. "**
4) In the GUI go to Billing -> Account Management. Does the project appear? **Yes**

Comment: @MartinZeitler Attempting to enable GAE results in an error "The Project ID specified is not available. Please select another."

Comment: Can you go to that Project ID and manage it? Note: Please edit your question with details instead of using comments. Your question needs the details, people often do not bother with questions that have long comment threads.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, I updated the question with as much detail as I can. Yes I am able to manage the project, I have owner rights to it.

Comment: I think this issue comes from an issue with the default service Account for App Engine. Does it exist in the project?

Comment: Hi, Can you please go to console-> App Engine-> Services and check if there are any services present?

Answer (score 0):

the error you encountered during the initialization of App Engine could be due to a region mismatch between your Firestore database and the ***region*** specified when creating the App Engine instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).